# housenumber automatically converted to date in xl sheet

Tags: php, xls

I'm using php for my coding.,

I'm downloading the data into msxl from dashboard, in which one field is housenumber,  when I look into the downloaded xl data everything is fine but the housenumber field is getting displayed as date format,

for eg: the entered date is 10-61 it showed me as oct-61
[in my dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKjT2.jpg)
[after downloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGPlF.jpg)

How can I get the correct housenumber after importing,

Any help regarding this..?